# Hive: How to Handle files which has delimiter in the data file?

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hql

I have the below data that needs to be insert into a hive table. The data has the default delimiter in the file. How to insert into a hive table?

```
10,Andrew,Man”,”ager,DE,PC
11,Arun,Manager,NJ,PC
12,Harish,Sales,NJ,MAC
13,Robert,Manager,PA,MAC
14,Laura,Engineer,PA,MAC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try using [CSV Serde](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/CSV+Serde)

> ```
> create table test_table(id int,...)
> ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
> WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
>    "separatorChar" = ",",
>    "quoteChar"     = "”",
>    "escapeChar"    = "\\"
> )
> ```

change quoteChar based on the data

Comment: Used below DDL
create table Names(
EmployeeID INT,
FirstName STRING, 
Title STRING,
State STRING, 
Laptop STRING
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.OpenCSVSerde'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
   "separatorChar" = ",",
   "quoteChar"     = "”",
   "escapeChar"    = "\\"
)
STORED AS TEXTFILE; 
But ',' is not displayed in the table.
"10"    "Andrew"        "Man    ager"   "DE"
"11"    "Arun"  "Manager"       "NJ"    "PC"
"12"    "Harish"        "Sales" "NJ"    "MAC"
"13"    "Robert"        "Manager"       "PA"    "MAC"
"14"    "Laura" "Engineer"      "PA"    "MAC"

Answer (score 0):

You have two options first you can used `"|"` (pipe) as delimiter and then insert into a hive table otherwise you have to enclose your data fields in double quotes `" "`, then use the OpenCSV Serde when creating the DDL for your Hive table. Now you can query the table and Hive will correctly display the data.